# using grpc on virtual machines

Tags: grpc

I am using a grpc example on kvm virtual machines and my goal is to modify it so that client and server can communicates over my shared memory.
I have already the mechanism for shared memory on vms but i have some issues with grpc.My question is:

what files i need to change? I have already ran a hello World  example with grpc and  i want to modify it in order to use my protocol over shared memory ( ../include/grpc++/impl/client_unary_call.h ? class  BlockingUnaryCall ?)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an endpoint backed by shared memory to get this going. See: grpc/src/core/iomgr/endpoint.h